# Why we need to have 2>&1 in /dev/null 2>&1?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I saw in linux script there was a command argument `> /dev/null 2>&1`, I know it is to redirect the output to null, means silencing it. I also know about the numbering for 0,1,2 (STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR), but I don't get why need to have this line?

```
2>&1
```

Basically I want to know what is the difference between

```
>/dev/null
```

and

```
>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`2>&1` will redirect stderr to wherever stdout currently points to. The argument `>/dev/null` will redirect stdout to `/dev/null` i.e discard/silent the output by command. But if you also want to discard (make silent) the stderr, then after redirecting stdout to `/dev/null`, specify `2>&1` to redirect stderr to the same place.

Example (For visualizing difference):

```
$ ls
file1
file2
```

```
$ ls file1 > /dev/null
$
```

Here the output of `ls file1` is `file1` which is sent to `/dev/null` and hence we get nothing. But:

```
$ ls file12 > /dev/null
ls: cannot access file12: No such file or directory
```

which gives stderr and as only output is sent to `/dev/null`. So, **If you want to discard/silent stderr also then you can redirect stderr to stdout and hence both will be sent to `/dev/null`** as follows:

```
$ ls file12 >/dev/null 2>&1
$
```

---

**Note** that the order/sequence of redirection matters. `2>&1` to redirect standard error must always be placed after redirecting standard output or it doesn't do anything. In above example if you run `ls file12 2>&1 >/dev/null` you will see the stderr printed to the terminal; if you run `ls file12 >/dev/null 2>&1` you won't.

- Alternatively You could also use `ls file1 file12 2>/dev/null 1>&2` with the same effect—which first redirects stderr to `/dev/null` and then redirects stdout to point to the same place stderr is currently pointing to.
- With the new version of bash you can also use **`>&`** simply like: `ls file12 >& /dev/null` which will redirects both stdout & stderr to `/dev/null`

Comment: Huh, I did not know that `>&` works the same as `&>`.  Learn something new every few minutes.  :)

Comment: It would be nice to know which version of bash started supporting >&.

Answer (score 2):

`someprogram > /dev/null 2>&1` works by redirecting the standard output (`&1`) to `/dev/null`, and then redirects standard error (`&2`) to the same place that `&1` has been redirected to.  If you do not also redirect stderr, then while standard output will be eliminated, standard error will still be sent to the terminal.

Comment: is 2>&1 executed first before someprogram > /dev/null?

Comment: It's not executed as it's not a program; it redirects output from the program that you are executing.  `someprogram > /dev/null` can actually be rewritten as `someprogram 1> /dev/null`.  Rather than using `2>&1`, you can also use `someprogram 1> /dev/null 2> /dev/null`, but Unix administrators are lazy, and that's more typing.

Comment: with the bash shell, the reason use `2>&1` instead of `/dev/null 2> /dev/null` is to prevent having two independent FDs working on the same destination or source. This process is called duplicating FDs. In the case of sending output to `/dev/null` you wont notice the difference, but if you were redirecting to a log the two FD's could clobber each others output.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I think 3172596 is actually asking if this redirection is *processed* from last to first. POSIX "Shell Command Language" sec 2.7 says "the order of evaluation is from beginning to end". Just look at it as something like 'so we pointed `&1` to `/dev/null`, now pointing `&2` to `&1` will naturally point us there too.'